# PyQGIS chaining consecutive processing algorithms timing Issue

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing

I am trying to run the *merge vector layers* algorithm for multiple shapefiles. Then run the *join attributes by location* between a merged polygon shapefile and merged multiline shapefile. All files are placed in the same directory.

The problem I am having is that once the merge vector layers algorithm is completed, the join attributes by location algorithm cannot find the *merged vector layer files* and triggers an error message:

> List out of range for 'INPUT' in the join attributes by location algorithm.

Running the same script twice, I am able to execute the join attribute by location algorithm without errors, but running the script once causes an issue.

I tried using QgsTask and QgsTaskManager to control the timing of both processing algorithms waiting on a complete signal for the task. However, I still run into the issue. I also tried time.sleep() to try to delay the time between the 2 algorithms, but that did not work as well.

How can I get a complete signal from 1 processing algorithm to trigger the execution of the next processing algorithm? Or if that's not the issue, what the heck is going on?

```
  out_path = os.path.join(loc,shape_type[0])
        parameters = {'LAYERS': shape_type[1], 
                      'CRS': 'EPSG:4326', 
                      'OUTPUT': out_path}
        
        #run merging algrithm n times depending on number of shape file subtypes
        merge_layers =processing.run("qgis:mergevectorlayers", parameters)

 #join use predicate 'crosses' =6, 
    #take attributes of first located feature only one feature to one feature transform = 1
    parameters = {'INPUT': SHAPEFILE_SUBTYPES[0][1][0], 
                    'JOIN': SHAPEFILE_SUBTYPES[1][1][0],
                    'PREDICATE': 6,
                    'METHOD': 1,
                  'OUTPUT': out_path}
    
    #run spatial inner join algorithm
    processing.run("qgis:joinattributesbylocation", parameters)
```

Comment: Whats `SHAPEFILE_SUBTYPES`, show how you create it

Comment: SHAPEFILE_SUBTYPES = [ ("file1.shp",["merged_polyshp.shp"]) , ("file2.shp", ["merged_lineshp.shp"])

**file1.shp and **file2.shp are placeholder names.